# Popular MySQL rss feeds

Tags: mysql, rss

Are there any popular Mysql rss feeds you guys can recommend? IBM has random articles but those are usually not enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/ has a feed of developer articles.

Answer (score 2):

Planet Mysql is an obvious answer.  It's a blog aggregator.  Of course there are other sites that are not included in this aggregation, but this one has more than any other single site.

http://www.planetmysql.org/rss20.xml

Answer (score 1):

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/feed/

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com